# Using the element of an array for an algorithm in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to solve an issue that takes the starting population of a group of animals, and a certain percentage of the population grows with each population. 
For instance, if the population started at 100, grew 50% in the first generation, then 20% in the second generation, the answer would be solved by:

```
startPop = finalPop
finalPop = 100 + (100 * 50%) - after 1st generation
finalPop = 150 + (150 * 20%)  - after 2nd generation
finalPop = 180
```

I need to solve this issue using an array that contains the growth rates for 5 generations. For example:

```
 int[] iaGrowthRate = new int{10,20,30,40,50,60}
```

How do I create code that will output the final population using the array?

Answer (score 0):

This can be trivially accomplished using a for loop to iterate over the population growth array:

```
private double getPopulationAfterGrowth(double startingPopulation, int... growth) {
    for (int g : growth) {
        startingPopulation = startingPopulation * (1 + ((double) g / 100));
    }
    return startingPopulation;
}
```